# How to decompile a 16 bit dos executable?

Tags: dos, 16-bit

I have a 104 byte dos program that I was expecting output from when run. I did not get any and so want to decompile it and find what it is doing. It is small enough that I could do this by hand, but I cannot find any of the hex code instructions. Is there anywhere I could find them or a program that can decompile it

Answer (score 3):

The tool you are looking for is called a Disassembler.  You can find one quite easily by doing a Google search.  One comes to mind is NASM's disassembler.  [I even have one I use](http://www.fysnet.net/newbasic.htm).

However, it isn't as simple as just running it through a disassembler.  Is the app an .EXE file or a .COM file.  If it is a .COM file, it is actually quite a bit easier if you tell the disassembler to start with an offset of 100h.

If it is an .EXE, you will need to parse the file's header (a tool can be found at the link above) and find the entry point and offset.  Then you can disassemble the correct parts.

Even after that, you will need to work with the output to find out more about the app.  Since it is only 104 bytes, that should be a very simple task.  Imagine doing it for 104,000 byte file.  Been there, done that.

Comment: With 104 byte it can't be an exe ;-)

Comment: @Marged, why do you say that? The standard DOS EXE header is only 28 bytes. With a required minimum 16 bytes for the relocation entry space, paragraph aligned sections, the code could start at byte 48 leaving 56 bytes for code space (with a 104-byte file). [Fifty-six bytes](http://www.hugi.scene.org/compo/compoold.htm) is a lot of room to do a lot of stuff.  Just for fun I quickly hard-coded an .exe file, byte for byte, to print 'Hello, World!' to the screen, and it uses a mere 79 bytes total, including the header and unused relocation space. "Who will ever need more than 64k of RAM?"

Comment: I confused this with the size of a boot sector and assumed a minimal exe header of 512 bytes. But using a decompiler like Ida will remove the need to know these details. For a lower level tool like debug they would be necessary

Comment: Just for fun, and if you care to take a look, I made a small "[Proof of Concept](http://www.fysnet.net/blog/2020/01/)" post showing a 59-byte 'Hello, World!' app.

Comment: A good read. And thanks for adding "inadvertently" ;-)